# Press button dynamically created to show hidden radio option list

Tags: javascript, jquery

In

```
<script>
   $all_hier_radio.on("change", function() {
   // Grab an input radio checked handler
   // Hide the radio options
   $all_hier_div.hide();
   $all_hier_radio.hide();

   // Create a button to be added to another div like this:
 $hierarq_but = $("<button/>", {  
    text: $hier_div_checked_id.text(),                    
                  type: "button",                    
                  id: "btn_hier",                      

            }); 
    // Append the button to another div
```

Whe a user selects one of the options, the list gets no visible, so it's fine.
But, I'd like that when a user clicks that button, the previously hidden radio option list could be displayed again

```
    $("button#btn_hier").bind("click", resetHierarquia());
</script>
```

And in another file,

```
function resetHierarquia() {                                            
    console.log("RRRRRREEEESSSSEETT");
    //$(this).preventDefault();
    //$(this).stopPropagation();
    $all_hier_div.show();
    $all_hier_radio.show();                                         
}
```

But I dont' get the desired effect.  Please take into consideration that I'm delving into javascript for the first time...

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle

Comment: Instead of creating the button dynamically, why don't you create it statically and hide it until you want it to be usable?

Comment: This line `$("button#btn_hier").bind("click", resetHierarquia());`should be like this `$("button#btn_hier").bind("click", resetHierarquia);` because you doesn't call the function but pass it in parameter.

Comment: @Biduleohm You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```js
$("button#btn_hier").bind("click", resetHierarquia());
```

It should be like this:

```js
$("button#btn_hier").bind("click", resetHierarquia);
```

It's because you don't want to call the function `resetHierarquia` but pass it in parameter to the event listener.

Comment: That does the trick, thanks.  May I ask you to reference me where I can find the rationale behind this on the jquery.com site, or in another one?

Comment: It's a part of the javascript language. A good ressource is the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) which is very clear. You also have the [jQuery API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/) if your search is specifically about jQuery.